# How can I mute phone ringing with exceptions?

Tags: iphone, audio

My mother is ailing and I want her to be able to reach me all the time. Also when asleep etc. Is it possible to disable all (phone) sounds with exceptions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can activate the `Do Not Disturb mode`.

In the settings, it lets you choose to allow calls from your favorites. So if you only add your mother’s number to your favorites, it will have the desired outcome.